# How to write a recipe common to both .c and cpp files

Tags: makefile, gnu, prerequisites

I want to compile both `.c` and `.cpp` files using same compiler command like

```
CC=g++
...
OBJS=mora.o
all : $(OBJS) libMO.so
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CCFLAGS) -c $(<) -o $(@)
libMO.so: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CCFLAGS)  $(^) -o $(@)
```

Now the question is how to include rule/recipe for `.cpp` files too? Can we do it in same rule using regex for prerequiste?

Is it ok to write one more rule/recipe for `.cpp` ?

```
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CCFLAGS) -c $(<) -o $(@)
%.o: %.cpp
        $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CCFLAGS) -c $(<) -o $(@)
```

Will the above 1st recipe give error for `.cpp` files as it will not find correspoding `.c` file ?

Comment: That is perfectly fine. Testing it would have told you that.

Comment: As Etan said, it should work fine.  I'm less convinced about the motivations, though; C and C++ are two different languages (for all that most of my C code compiles under a C++ compiler, I don't pretend that the code is anything other than C code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it ok to write one more rule/recipe for `.cpp` ?

Yes it is. You can write a rule for each extension you need Make to process. If you redefine the same pattern, [make will choose the first one found in the makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match).

> Will the above 1st recipe give error for `.cpp` files as it will not find corresponding `.c` file ?

Make will process `.cpp` files independently of `.c` files, and vice versa (unless you explicitely tell him not to, e.g. if a `.c` file depends of a `.cpp` file).

---

That said, a little review :

- Special variables like `$(<)` or `$(@)` do not need parenthesis. You can write `$<` and `$@` directly.
- C and C++ rules share the same built-in `$(CPPFLAGS)` variable (meant for preprocessor flags, your `$(INCLUDE)` variable content should go into).
- C uses the `$(CC)` and `$(CFLAGS)` built-in variables :

  ```make
  CC = $(CXX)
  ...
  %.o: %.c
      $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
  ```
- C++ uses the `$(CXX)` and `$(CXXFLAGS)` built-in variables :

  ```make
  %.o: %.cpp
      $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
  ```
- GNU Make already has built-in rules for C and C++ source files. Using the above variables right, there is no need for you to specify these generic rules at all.